How to get gmailr to connect
I cannot access my gmail through the r gmailr package:
library(gmailr)

# Set the path to the OAuth credentials JSON file
gm_auth_configure(path = "gmail_auth.json")

# Authenticate - this will open a browser where you'll log into your Google account
gm_auth()

opens the gmail signin page with the error "Access Blocked: This App's request is invalid"
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
